# Covering space of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology

How to show that $\mathbb{R} \times (0,+\infty) \times \mathbb{R}$ is a universal cover of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ by Iwasawa Decomposition?

**My attempt** By Iwasawa Decomposition, for any $A \in \mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$, we have
$$
A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos \theta & -\sin \theta \\
\sin \theta & \cos \theta
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
r & 0 \\
0 & \frac 1r
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & x \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Thus we get a map $\varphi: \mathbb{R} \times (0,+\infty) \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$. I think it's sufficient to show that $\mathbb{R}$ is a universal cover of the subspace
$$
\left\{
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos \theta & -\sin \theta \\
\sin \theta & \cos \theta
\end{pmatrix}
:
\theta \in \mathbb{R}
\right\}.
$$
But I don't know how to show it rigorously. Can you give me some hints?

Comment: I don't understand why this was downvoted.

Comment: the subspace you mention is homeomorphic to a circle (basically, the parametrisation you gave factors into the homeomorphism). Hope that helps.

Comment: @user120527 Thanks! It's a good explaination.